# How do I find the exact size of my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am currently trying to use `paintComponent` to draw a square in the middle of my `JFrame` on top of a `JPanel`. The size of my frame is 600 x 600, but when I try to draw the square with Xcoordinate = 300 and Ycoordinate = 300 the square is not really even close to the middle of my Frame.

Am I doing something wrong? This is for a school project, so any tips would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

> Write a complete working program that draws a square in the middle of the 
>   frame.
>   When the user clicks on a square (left click), it then replaces it with 4 
>   smaller
>   squares drawn in separate quadrants, each of which is a quarter of the size 
>   of the original
>   square and has random color. If user clicks (right click) on any square, it 
>   is removed/deleted from the frame.
>
> If user remains inactive for 15 seconds ( (i.e., stops clicking), all squares should start moving away
>   from the center (any speed is fine, overlaps are fine but not preferred). If squares, hit the edges,
>   they are deleted again. If user presses 'S', the squares stop moving. The frame is cleared when user
>   presses 'Delete' key three times in quick succession (within 3 seconds) and you start all over again.
>
> Test your program to draw unique patterns.

My frame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SquareFrame extends JFrame {
    private final int WIDTH = 600, HEIGHT = 600;
    private final Dimension frameSize;
    private SquarePanel panel;
    public SquareFrame(){
        panel = new SquarePanel();
        frameSize = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        this.setTitle("Sqaures");
        this.setSize(frameSize);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    SquareFrame frame = new SquareFrame();
}
}
```

My panel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class SquarePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public SquarePanel(){
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Square test = new Square();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(test.x,test.y,test.width,test.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
}
```

My square class:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Square extends Rectangle {
    public Square(){
        this.height = 100;
        this.width = 100;
        this.x = 300;
        this.y = 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"in the middle of the frame"* By 'frame' I think they mean 'drawing surface' (as in the `JPanel`). **Check with whoever issued this task.** If that is the case, the best approach would be to use the current dimensions of the panel when calculating where to draw the square(s).

Answer (score 0):

> Write a complete working program that draws a square in the middle of the 
>   frame.

Well, I think that is a terrible requirement. The frame contains a title bar and 4 borders. As the frame shrinks in size you won't be able to paint the square on the title bar.

Custom painting is done on the panel that is added to the frame. So I think you should really be trying to center the panel in the bounds of the panel. You need to clarify the actual requirement.

> public class Square extends Rectangle {

Why are you extending Rectangle?

If you need, the x, y, width, height information then you just use the `getBounds()` method of the `Rectangle` class to get the information.

However, you don't need the x/y values.

If you want to center the rectangle then you need to calculate the x/y values dynamically as you do your custom painting based on the current size of the panel.

What you need to know is the width/height of the rectangle you want to paint, so really you should be creating a `Dimension` object. Something like:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(100, 100);
```

Then to center the rectangle in the panel you need to know the width of the panel and the width of the rectangle to calculate the location to do the painting of the rectangle:

```
int x = (getWidth() - d.getWidth()) / 2;
int y = ...
g.drawRect(x, y, d.width, d.height);
```